# DIV que começa no fim de uma outra div e vai até o final da div pai

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap-3

eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="pai">
   <div class="t1">
      itens
   </div>
   <div class="t2">
      itens2
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.pai{
   height:100%;
}
.t1{
   height:20%;
}
.t2{
   height:80%;
}
```

Basicamente esta e minha estrutura. Para uma tela 1080p os 20% são suficiente para exibir os itens que eu tenho dentro da div t1. Porem quando eu abro em uma tela 720p ele corta uma parte dos itens. como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Figura 1]

Como podem observar a parte t1 é a que tem a barra de pesquisar e o botão azul que quase não aparece. Como a tela é menor os 20% não foram suficiente para exibir os 2 itens (barra de busca e botão azul). Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma que ele calcula essa porcentagem automaticamente para que ele não corte uma devido ao fato de ela não caber nos 20%. ou seja mudar essas porcentagens de acordo com o necessário (devido a resolução da tela)

Comment: Estranho este comportamento, pq se vc está utilizando %, independente do tamanho da tela, a div t1, sempre vai ter 20% de altura.

Comment: sim. Porem creio que os componentes não sejam responsivos. e em uma tela menor ocupem mais de 20% da tela.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas com CSS você não irá conseguir fazer isso porque ele não tem como saber a altura dos elementos de forma dinâmica. Como está usando Bootstrap, um pequeno código jQuery irá resolver o problema, ajustando a `div` de baixo automaticamente de acordo com a altura da `div` pai e da `div` de cima.

Basta inserir o código na sua página:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   var t1_height = $(".t1").outerHeight(); // pega a altura de .t1
   var pai_height = $(".pai").outerHeight(); // pega a altura do .pai

   $(".t2").css({
      "height": pai_height-t1_height+"px"
   });
});
```

Veja em funcionamento:

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   var t1_height = $(".t1").outerHeight(); // pega a altura de .t1
   var pai_height = $(".pai").outerHeight(); // pega a altura do .pai
   
   $(".t2").css({
      "height": pai_height-t1_height+"px"
   });
});
```

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
.pai{
   height:100%;
   background: yellow;
}
.t1{
   background: red;
}
.t2{
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pai">
   <div class="t1">
      itens
      <br>
      mais itens  
   </div>
   <div class="t2">
      itens2
   </div>
</div>
```